# Logging with Selenium Server?

Tags: selenium, python

Right now I have several Python Selenium scripts in which I am manually writing results to a text file. Is there a more standardized / centralized way I can log my results without much difficulty?

I googled around but only see complicated setups involving specific technologies, like integrating into Nant. I just want a logging system that will allow me to review test results in a central place when I kick off multiple `.py` files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest doing a Google search for "Python unit testing framework".  A good unit testing framework will provide a way to log test results.

Alternatively, you could do a Google search for "python logging package", which would reveal APIs for generic, non-test-specific logging.  If you have further questions about Python logging packages, I suggest posting your question in StackOverflow rather than here; while there are surely people here who know about that subject, there will be many, many more in StackOverflow.

Comment: Thanks. I'm going to spend today reading about unittest and nose. Links for people who may come across this thread in the future: http://docs.python.org/library/unittest.html http://readthedocs.org/docs/nose/en/latest/

Comment: I do prefer nose over pyunit or separately logging the verification steps

Answer (score 2):

You can launch each of your test jobs as a separate job with the [Jenkins CI](http://jenkins-ci.org/) server.   Jenkins can render a HTML report for each of your JUnit .xml test results that are generated.  I'd say that is the quickest/easiest way to do it.   Obviously, if you are using [Py.Test](http://pytest.org/latest/) or [Nose](https://github.com/nose-devs/nose), you will get this sort of output.

If you don't use that method , then you need to code something with the framework you are using, or with the build tool you are using (Gradle, Ant, or Maven).